# how to assign User defined date in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to assign a date for the user to give manual date as input and make use of input at later stage. when the user inserted manual date , it has to be used for the naming conventions for the file name. Ex `football 20160601.xlsx`

I have gone through some website but could not able to find any answers as per my requirement.

My code:

```
Sub date()
    date_test = Now()    

        Range("A1") = Format(date_test, "mm.dd.yy") ' how to aassign this date as a user defined date( as manual date) something like msg box but not msgbox.

    End date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim inputDate as Date
Date = Format(InputBox("Enter a Date", "Input"),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Something like this?

If you want a Datepicker to select the desired date, then create a new userform and add the "Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control" (Tools->Additional Controls) to the Form. Then you can use it's value like this: `Format(DatePicker1.Value,"yyyymmdd")`